# I need browser verification by two different domain

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to verify browser.

Example. I am using chrome browser and I want to make sure the get/post request have sent from another tab of same browser.

Comment: Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: and have you **tried anything yourself** so far?

Comment: @RobinSingh What's wrong with question?

Comment: @MohammadEmrulHassan show your code that you try otherwise nobody will help you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `$_SERVER` super global:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php